# Harddrive disconnects when I try to write on it

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, sata

One of the four internal harddrives (SATA) of my computer is causing me some trouble.

This drive only have one NTFS partition. Everytime I try to copy a file on it, the copy eventually fails after a few seconds, and the disk completely disappear from my OS (Win 7).

Even if I take a look at the Disk Management tool (in Computer Management window), the drive isn't there. The only way to make the drive reappear is to restart the computer.

I did an error check, and nothing came up. This drive worked fine in this configuration for at least a year before starting to do this.

Any idea on what could cause the problem, or on what I should be looking for?

Comment: I would try disconnecting and then reconnecting it to the motherboard - it could just be a loose connection.

Comment: This sounds like your hdd is about to fail.  Check the S.M.A.R.T data on the failing hdd.  I have a similar problem and the drive is failing.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to answer. I had a bunch of other problems with my computer to fix first. The SMART check didn't find anything. In the end, D. Strout was right: reconnecting the wires did the trick, even if everything seemed well connected. Thanks to both of you